# How do I auto format the y axis in a line chart using a specific cell value

Tags: excel

I have a line chart that is linked to a dataset that is conditionally formatted using the value in a specific cell on the same tab.
When I change the cell it changes the formatting of the dataset from £'s say to %'s BUT the y axis formatting does not update.
Is there a way to change this automatically? I have tried linking the data source etc and it doesn't work.
Maybe VBA is the answer?

Maybe VBA is the answer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you should add some details to demonstrate the issue